# Python, Jinja2 nl2br and security

Tags: python, xss, jinja2

I'm using the [snippet from Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) for showing multiline texts in html and I'm facing an issue :

If the user enters

```
"Hello\nMy name is Jon"
```

the `nl2br` tag will render it as

```
"Hello<br />My name is Jon"
```

with the br correctly interpreted (a break line).

Now this is good, but if the user enters

```
"Hello<script>alert('hacked');</script>"
```

since I have to interpret the html to show the breaklines correctly, the `<script>` will also be executed...

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you've linked to *already* escapes the input prior to replacing newlines.  Subsequently, the text is marked safe, because at that point it is.  The relevant code is:

```
from jinja import escape, Markup
value = escape(value)
return Markup(value)
```

For the input `"Hello<script>alert('hacked');</script>"`, this results in `"Hello &lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hacked&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;"`.  Notice that the problematic syntax has been replaced with escape characters.  When rendered in the HTML document, there will be no script execution, just text.